# Traefik causing very slow LAN speeds and router crash

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I've recently been trying to migrate my home server to a Docker microservice style setup. I've installed fresh Ubuntu Server 18.04, set up Traefik container and Nextcloud container, but am experiencing a peculiar issue.

When I access Nextcloud over the internet it works OK, however on LAN I connect to the website, attempt to download a file and the download is extremely slow for a few seconds before making my router reboot itself. I have tried a Jellyfin container as well and the behavior is the same, so not an issue with Nextcloud. I have tried exposing the ports of the service containers directly and then the issue is resolved, most probably issue is with Traefik.

Here's my [traefik.toml](https://hastebin.com/raw/oheyusiqiv), [docker-compose.yml](https://hastebin.com/raw/udelanohaz), and [Traefik container](https://hastebin.com/raw/uwexikebaw) configuration.

I'd greatly appreciate any help, as I would like to use Traefik as a reverse proxy, not directly expose any ports. :-)

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd put the (relevant) content of your config files in your question. This helps for two things. First it makes them persistent here so they won't get lost if sth on the linked pages changes. Second it makes them findable via search. :)

Comment: @Markus the problem is I have no idea what may be causing the issue, so I included all of my configuration.